# How to uninstall the snap version of digiKam?

Tags: apt, uninstall, snap, digikam

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, and just installed the digiKam snap via the snap store. It won't run. Further, when I use these terminal commands ...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove digikam
```

I'm told digiKam is not installed. However, the icon for digiKam is in my apps drawer.

I'm an idiot, I guess, for installing an app via the snap beta channel. However, digiKam is all over the net as being the best image management solution for Linux. Right now, it's like crabs.

Comment: Did you try `sudo snap remove digikam`? Remove it the same way you installed it.

Comment: `apt-get` ONLY works on deb packages. It has no idea of rpms, AppImages, Flatpaks, Zipfiles, Snaps, or other non-debs. Oh, and you can get rid of those crabs very easily with a bit of careful grooming.

Comment: Well paint me foolish. I didn't even think about apt-get and snaps! Now to get a fine comb. Thanks guys.

Comment: Please accept @ChrisAga's answer by checking the mark next to it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Calling something a STD is not nice. Please provide meaningful titles to your question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jos already stated in a comment, the right command to remove the snap package is `snap`, not `apt` :
`sudo snap remove digikam`

Then you can install the stable version from the digiKam page : 
https://www.digikam.org/download/
It's an AppImage so you have not to struggle with snap.
I was a little bit reluctant at first, but nobody maintain a ppa repository with up to date version of digiKam and it's not often updated so downloading an AppImage is fine.

Answer (score 0):

*digikam* has a snap package which is provided by a community member. 
See https://snapcraft.io/digikam

You will notice that there is a *beta* package (6.4.0, from December 2019) and a *edge* package (7.0.0beta, from today) for digikam. There is no stable package yet. If the package from the *beta* channel did not work for you, try the one from the *edge* channel.